# 3D - spline for trajectory generation in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, interpolation, spline

I am currently trying to create a 3D trajectory for a robot end-effector in Octave.
The end-effector is supposed to visit a set of 3D points `X = [x_1 ,..., x_n]`, where `x_i = [xcoord_i; ycoord_i; zcoord_i]`. Simple linear interpolation would lead to non-smooth robot movements. Hence I want to generate a *3D-spline* curve that generates N 3D points between my reference points. There exists an Matlab implementation for this kind of task ([documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/constructing-spline-curves-in-2d-and-3d.html#zmw57dd0e3517)). Can you give me a hint on how to approach this kind of problem in ***Octave***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do three one-dimensional spline interpolation on `X(1,:)`, `X(2,:)` and `X(3,:)` using `interp1`, see
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/One_002ddimensional-Interpolation.html

This should work:

```
t = 1:n;
ti = 0:0.01:n;
xi = interp1(t, X(1,:), ti, "spline"); 
yi = interp1(t, X(2,:), ti, "spline"); 
zi = interp1(t, X(3,:), ti, "spline"); 
Xi = [xi; yi; zi];
```

Of course, you should adapt `t` and `ti` to your needs.